# Scipy Draw Exponential - How Do I Fit This Better?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm new to plotting in Python, so please bear with me. I've searched and read a lot today, but am unable to figure this out.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def exp_func(x,a,b,c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c

x = np.array(df_auction_cat['AgeAdj'])
y = np.array(df_auction_cat['SP/ABCost'])

plt.scatter(x, y, s=50, cmap='Blues', alpha=0.7, edgecolor='gray', linewidth=1)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_func, x, y)
plt.plot(x, exp_func(x, *popt))
```

Earlier in the code I manipulate some data and put together the df_auction_cat dataset. The scatter looks like this, and the exponential doesn't fit at all:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Datapoints below:

```
AgeAdj SP/ABCost
26 0.051851813
8 0.342104363
28 0.142081738
23 0.1
22 0.056330527
19 0.157692308
18 0.157301407
17 0.15
17 0.236690872
17 0.173041737
14 0.223076923
12 0.247294549
12 0.242445636
10 0.464864865
17 0.233333333
17 0.253333333
10 0.292307692
28 0.126554024
19 0.322973634
14 0.270684988
18 0.174560858
12 0.203654335
23 0.133144882
17 0.119076601
12 0.381578947
17 0.232747811
14 0.365465999
11 0.574056541
19 0.153471963
29 0.128023925
15 0.164999835
28 0.140513444
22 0.089770069
16 0.16001412
15 0.283422611
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own x, y and worked, can you post your input data?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def exp_func(x,a,b,c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c

x = np.array(range(0,100))
y = np.array(exp_func(x,0.1,0.1,.1)*50+np.random.rand(100))

plt.scatter(x, y, s=50, cmap='Blues', alpha=0.7, edgecolor='gray', linewidth=1)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_func,x, y)
plt.plot(x, exp_func(x, *popt))
```

Comment: Hi Yongkang, please see above for an edit of my original post. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out! I didn't realize you have to sort the x values in ascending order. I also provided an initial guess in this line of code:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_func, x, y, p0=(0.7,0.1,1))
```

I tried graphing without sorting and saw this. I read about needing to sort values.
[image]

Sorting fixed the issue:
[image]